# 'Endless Runner' Game Background in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm wanting to make an 'endless runner' game. So, I need a random scrolling background to act as the obstacles, platforms, ground, and background in general. It needs to be random though and not the same background repeated over and over.

The background I'm wanting to do is too complexed for tiles (or at least I don't think so). It will be a similar complexity to this game: http://www.mochigames.com/game/flood-runner-3/

How would I go about coding this?

Answer (score 1):

There're lots of tutorials out there, you can try google firstly with "side-scrolling game" or "platformer game":

http://as3gametuts.com/2011/11/11/platformer-1/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k38YrVxXkSM

etc...

And in my opinion, [Circus Engine](http://citrusengine.com/)

is a great engine for platformer game in as3.